# Hyperledger-fabric blockchain Multi Host

Tags: docker, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I am working on hyperledger fabric and I would like to have some guidance in using hyperledger fabric with multiple hosts. I have an orderer, a ca, two peers (Peer 0 and Peer 1) and two hosts (10.10.10.x and 10.10.11.x). I have the orderer, ca and Peer0 in host - 1 and Peer1 in a separate host (i.e) Peer 0 in host-1 and Peer 1 alone on host-2.

I need to connect Peer1 in host 2 to Peer0 in host 1. I can achieve this scenario while having multiple hosts in the same network using docker swarm and overlay network (i.e) hosts are in same IP range (10.10.10.x), but while trying to do this in a host in a different network (10.10.11.X) I am unable to connect the peer to the host present in Machine-1. I had done the multihost network by referring [this](https://medium.com/@wahabjawed/hyperledger-fabric-on-multiple-hosts-a33b08ef24f) link.

```
Docker Version used:
[root@node2 composer]# docker -v
Docker version 18.03.1-ce, build 9ee9f40
```

Comment: If your don't want to go in to much deatils of deployment and just need to deploy multihost blockchain. You should check hyperledger-cello. https://cello.readthedocs.io . Cello has support for deploying hyperledger-fabric

Answer (score 1):

Add extra_host entry in docker-compose.yml file like this:

```
extra_hosts:
      - "peer0.org2.example.com:192.168.1.28" 
      - "ca.org2.example.com:192.168.1.28"   
      - "peer0.org3.example.com:192.168.1.15"
      - "ca.org3.example.com:192.168.1.15"
```

Like this do entries for all orderers, CA, peers on both machines(hosts)

And do same host entry in host file:
sudo nano /etc/hosts - edit this file

```
192.168.1.28     peer0.org2.example.com
192.168.1.28     ca.org2.example.com
192.168.1.15     peer0.org3.example.com
192.168.1.15     ca.org3.example.com
```

Like this do entries for all orderers, CA, peers...on both machines(hosts)

Comment: Thanks for the quick turn around, will give it a shot

Comment: does this extra_hosts work for external IPs too ? what if i want to connect with my friends system

Answer (score 0):

Can you ping you machines?, maybe they can connect
Other thing that could be, you have to add an extra-hosts section to your docker-compose.yml files. That map your IP to the domain name in your docker containers.

```
extra_hosts:
- "peer1.org1.example.com:<Second machine IP address>"
```

I figured out how to setup a multihost Hyperledger Fabric not using Docker Swarm, and using the basic-network example included in the Hyperledger Fabric examples.

You can review it here, hope it helps you.

https://medium.com/1950labs/setup-hyperledger-fabric-in-multiple-physical-machines-d8f3710ed9b4