# migrate orderer on different server ( IBM-Hyperledger fabric 1.1)

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, ibm-blockchain

Is it possible to migrate orderer on different server, once we have setup the Blockchain Network. Currently Single Server is having 2 Organization with 1 peer each and solo orderer on same server(Similar to default byfn setup). Now I wanted to move the orderer container on diferent server. Could anyone share the steps.

Comment: I think you can refer to following link. [Hyperledger-fabric Multi-Host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51816525/hyperledger-fabric-blockchain-multi-host)

Comment: This link helped me to resolve my isue. I have seprated my orderer to different host now.
https://medium.com/@malliksarvepalli/hyperledger-fabric-on-multiple-hosts-using-docker-swarm-and-compose-f4b70c64fa7d